# Weights of network stays the same after optimizer step

Tags: neural-network, pytorch

My network just refuses to train. To make code reading less of a hassle, I abbreviate some complicated logic. Would update more if needed.

```py
model = DistMultNN()
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.0001)
for t in range(500):
    e1_neg = sampling_logic()
    e2_neg = sampling_logic()

    e1_pos = sampling_logic()
    r = sampling_logic()
    e2_pos = sampling_logic()
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    y_pred = model(tuple(zip(e1_pos, r, e2_pos)), e1_neg, e2_neg)
    loss = model.loss(y_pred)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

I define my network as follow

```py
class DistMultNN(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.seed = 42
        self.entities_embedding = nn.init.xavier_uniform_(
            torch.zeros((self.NO_ENTITIES, self.ENCODING_DIM), requires_grad=True))
        self.relation_embedding = nn.init.xavier_uniform_(
            torch.zeros((self.NO_RELATIONSHIPS, self.ENCODING_DIM), requires_grad=True))
        self.W = torch.rand(self.ENCODING_DIM, self.ENCODING_DIM, requires_grad=True)  # W is symmetric, todo: requireGrad?
        self.W = (self.W + self.W.t()) / 2
        self.b = torch.rand(self.ENCODING_DIM, 1, requires_grad=True)
        self.lambda_ = 1.
        self.rnn = torch.nn.RNN(input_size=encoding_dim, hidden_size=1, num_layers=1, nonlinearity='relu')
        self.loss_func = torch.nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1)

    def loss(self, y_pred):
        softmax = -1 * self.loss_func(y_pred)
        result = torch.mean(softmax[:, 0])
        result.requires_grad = True
        return result

    def forward(self, samples, e1neg, e2neg):
        batch_size = len(samples)
        batch_result = np.zeros((batch_size, len(e1neg[0]) + 1))
        for datapoint_id in range(batch_size):
            entity_1 = entities_embed_lookup(datapoint_id[0])
            entity_2 = entities_embed_lookup(datapoint_id[2])
            r = relation_embed_lookup(datapoint_id[1])
            x = self.some_fourier_transform(entity_1, r, entity_2)
            batch_result[datapoint_id][0] = self.some_matmul(x)
            for negative_example_id in range(len(e1neg[0])):
                same_thing_with_negative_examples()
                batch_result[datapoint_id][negative_example_id + 1] = self.some_matmul(x)
        batch_result_tensor = torch.tensor(data=batch_result)
        return batch_result_tensor
```

I tried checking weights using e.g. `print(model.rnn.all_weights)` in the training loop but they do not change. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Based on this line `result.requires_grad = True`, there is no `grad_fn` associated with the loss, therefore no gradient is ever computed.

Comment: Removing that line throws error “element 0 of tenders does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn”, which was the reason I added that line at first out of desperation :D

Comment: That is what I meant: this line is not solving the problem. It is clear why you did :) I just pointed out that this was a symptom. @Nopileos explained it in the answer below. We cannot pinpoint a solution, because you didn't provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

So first of all the `result.requires_grad = True` should not be needed and in fact should throw an error, because results would normally not be a leaf variable.

So in your forward at the end you create a new tensor out of a numpy array:

```
batch_result_tensor = torch.tensor(data=batch_result)
```

and out of this result you calculate the loss and want to backward it. This doesn't work because `batch_result_tensor` is not part of any computation graph needed to calculate a gradient. You can't just mix numpy and torch this way.

The forward function has to consists of operations with torch tensors, which require grad, if you want to update and optimize them. So the default case is you have layers, which have weight tensors which requires grad. You have a input which you pass to the layers and so the computational graph is build and all the operations are recorded in it.

So I would start making `batch_result` a torch tensor and remove `batch_result_tensor = torch.tensor(data=batch_result)` and  `result.requires_grad = True`. You might have to change more.